# Router randomly stops responding to anything

Tags: networking, router

My internet connection randomly stops working, and when it does, even 192.168.1.1 doesn't load. Both internet and router configuration either work fine, or none of them work at all.

The PON light is solid green, But the WiFi light blinks very slowly when router is not responding.

I have tried using LAN, but that is having same issue. I tried reseting the router multiple times but issue comes back within minutes.

Issue started when I switched internet provider.

Comment: Maybe try updating the router's firmware.

Comment: Agree with updating firmware and do a full hardware reset when you do this. Then set it up again

Comment: "Issue started when I switched internet provider." Contact ISP -- there may be specific settings that need to be changed for compatibility.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik they are pushing for their own router.

Comment: @John I am in contact with manufacturer. Seems like they don't provide firmware to end users. I might have to change the router.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the advice.. I think this could have solved the issue. But manufacturer denied me access to firmware.